# Accessing a list from a second form and adding user input to the list

Tags: c#

I have a list called "studentInfo" and I am trying to allow the user to go to a form I created called "addRecord" and type in a student code and a student mark and once they hit submit the data is then added to the list in form1 and then also the data gets added to the listbox in form1.

I don't know how to go about this since I am new to C# so any guidance will be appreciated.

My list is created like this

`public static List<string> studentInfo = new List<string>();`

Then once my form1 loads I read in from a CSV file to populate the listbox

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string lines, studentNumber, studentMark;  

            StreamReader inputFile; 

            inputFile = File.OpenText("COM122.csv");  

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)  
            {
                lines = inputFile.ReadLine(); 
                studentInfo = lines.Split(',').ToList(); 
                studentNumber = studentInfo[0];  
                studentMark = studentInfo[1];  
                lstMarks.Items.Add(studentNumber + " : " + studentMark);  
            }
            inputFile.Close();
        }
```

I want the user to go to the addRecord form, enter in a student code and student mark, then hit submit and then the program asks the user to confirm that the data they have entered is correct and then the user is directed back to form1 and the data will be in the listbox.

Comment: If you display your secondary form with `ShowDialog()`, then execution will stop in Form1.  To signify a confirmation from the user, set `DialogResult` in the second form.  This will be returned to `ShowDialog()` (back in Form1) where you can then query the secondary form for the entered information (setup some public properties to hold the new information to be added).

Comment: Would you be able to show some code examples? I don't understand what you mean, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transfer info from textboxes into a listbox in another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603800/how-to-transfer-info-from-textboxes-into-a-listbox-in-another-form)

Comment: After reading that post I don't think that answers my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, in Form addRecord, we create two properties to hold the data to be retrieved from the main Form.  This should only be done if addRecord returns DialogResult.OK.  I've added in two buttons, one for cancel and one for OK.  These simply set DialogResult to their respective results.  The property values for the two values to be returned are also set in the OK button handler:

```
public partial class addRecord : Form
{

    public addRecord()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _Student;
    public string Student
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Student;
        }
    }

    private string _Score;
    public string Score
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Score;
        }
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this._Student = this.tbStudent.Text;
        this._Score = this.tbScore.Text;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

}
```

Now, back in Form1, here is an example of showing addRecord with ShowDialog(), then retrieving the stored values when OK is returned:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public static List<string> studentInfo = new List<string>();

    // ... other code ...

    private void btnAddRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addRecord frmAddRecord = new addRecord();
        if (frmAddRecord.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            studentInfo.Add(frmAddRecord.Student);
            studentInfo.Add(frmAddRecord.Score);
            lstMarks.Items.Add(frmAddRecord.Student + " : " + frmAddRecord.Score);
        }
    }

}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Here's a different version of addRecord that doesn't allow you to hit OK until a valid name and a valid score have been entered.  Note that the property has been changed to int, and the TextChanged() events have been wired up to ValidateFields().  The OK button is also initially disabled:

```
public partial class addRecord : Form
{

    public addRecord()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.tbStudent.TextChanged += ValidateFields;
        this.tbScore.TextChanged += ValidateFields;
        btnOK.Enabled = false;
    }

    private string _Student;
    public string Student
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Student;
        }
    }

    private int _Score;
    public int Score
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Score;
        }
    }

    private void ValidateFields(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool valid = false; // assume invalid until proven otherwise
        // Make sure we have a non-blank name, and a valid mark between 0 and 100:
        if (this.tbStudent.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            int mark;
            if (int.TryParse(this.tbScore.Text, out mark))
            {
                if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100)
                {
                    this._Student = this.tbStudent.Text.Trim();
                    this._Score = mark;
                    valid = true; // it's all good!
                }
            }
        }
        this.btnOK.Enabled = valid;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , worked brilliantly, I was wondering how would I go about validating the user input so that the 'Mark' can only be an integer and between 0 and 100. I tried using int.tryParse but it doesn't play well with the get statement.

Comment: In  your "addRecord" form, use a [NumericUpDown Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netframework-4.7.2) for the score.  You can set the **Minimum** and **Maximum** properties to 0 and 100, which means it will always have a valid score in it.  The number is retrieved with the **Value** property, which returns a decimal, but you can cast it to an integer if you want only integral values.   Now simply change your Score property to return an integer or a decimal instead of a string.

Comment: Another tweak would be to wire up the TextChanged() event of the name textbox, then enable/disable the OK button based on whether the textbox is blank or not.  Now the user can only hit OK when there is a name, and the score will also be valid because of the NumericUpDown.

Comment: ```this._Mark = this.txtMark.Text;```
What would I change this line too? I get a cannot convert type string to int error

Comment: If you changed to a NumericUpDown, and your property is int, then something like `this._Mark  = (int)this.numericUpDown1.Value;`.

Comment: I haven't used a NumericUpDown, is there a way I can do it without that?

Comment: Sure...standby.

Comment: Thank you , I will be on standby

Comment: Thank you, works good, one last question would you be able to explain why you made 2 variables with the same name but one has an _ at the start? for example ```private string _StudentID;```

Comment: The underscored variable is a **backing field**.  See [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for more information.  You can use the newer, auto-implemented properties to get rid of these; I'm just old-school and stuck in my ways...